# Determine length of fixed-length string attribute from HDF5 file in C

Tags: c, hdf5

I have an HDF5 file with the following contents:

```
$ h5dump foo.h5 
HDF5 "foo.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   ATTRIBUTE "Version" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE 5;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
         CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1 ) / ( 1 ) }
      DATA {
      (0): "1.2.0"
      }
   }
...
```

How do I extract the `STRSIZE` (in this case 5) from the attribute? I can currently extract the entire string by allocating more memory than I think I need:

```c
char version_string[] = "hello_hello_hello";
hid_t attr = H5Aopen(file_id, "Version", H5P_DEFAULT);
hid_t atype = H5Tcopy(H5T_C_S1);
H5Tset_size(atype, 17);
herr_t err = H5Aread(attr, atype, version_string);
H5Aclose(attr);
H5Tclose(atype);
```

However, I cannot figure out how to find allocate the *right* about of memory for the string.

Comment: Exactly what HDF5 library and version are you using?

Comment: @Dai: HDF5 version 1.12.1

Comment: Why does `version_string` have initial content from a string literal when you're overwriting it in `H5Aread`?

Comment: Why are you using `H5Tcopy`? You should be able to pass `H5T_C_S1` directly into `H5Aread`.

Comment: @Dai: It has initial content because I'm a terrible C programmer and was trying to avoid a malloc.

Comment: That's unsafe though - when dealing with data of varying size you'll eventually need to use `malloc` - or at least some kind of dynamic allocation system, especially when there's no upper-bound on string lengths (Fun fact: HDF5 supports strings sized in the gigabytes, which obviously can't be `malloc`'d in a 32-bit process, let alone statically allocated by the compiler, have fun with that :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm not a HDF5 user)

From looking at the documentation, I think you need to use `H5Aget_storage_size`  to determine the size of the buffer to use with `H5Aread`.

```
    hid_t versionAttr = H5Aopen( file_id, "Version", H5P_DEFAULT );
    if( versionAttr < 0 ) goto cleanup1;

    size_t versionAttrSize = 0;
    {
        hsize_t size = H5Aget_storage_size( versionAttr );
        if( size == 0 ) {
            // get_storage_size failed for some reason but the documentation isn't helpful. Grrrr.
            // TODO: Show an error message here, I guess.
            goto cleanup2;
        }
        else if( size > SIZE_MAX ) {
            // The data on-disk is larger than can be represented in C on your platform.
            // TODO: Show an error message here, I guess.
            goto cleanup2;
        }
        else {
            versionAttrSize = (size_t)size;
        }
    }

    char* versionAttrBuffer = malloc( versionAttrSize );
    if( !versionAttrBuffer ) {
        // Computer broken.
        goto cleanup2;
    }

    herr_t versionAttrBufferReadError = H5Aread( versionAttr, H5T_C_S1, versionAttrBuffer );
    if( versionAttrBufferReadError < 0 ) {
        goto cleanup3;
    }

    // Do stuff with `versionAttrBuffer` here.
    printf( "String attribute length: %d\n", versionAttrSize );
    printf( "String attribute data: \"%s\"", versionAttrBuffer );

cleanup3:
    free( versionAttrBuffer );

cleanup2:
    herr_t cleanupErr = H5Aclose( versionAttr );
    if( cleanupErr < 0 ) { die( "This should never happen." ); };

cleanup1:
    // TODO: Close file?
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Just validated this and ran it under ASan; it works.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that makes handling HDF5 files in C much easier is through the usage of [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com). To allocate the right amount of memory to store the value of an attribute of fixed-length string can be done as follows (in C using HDFql):

```
long long size;

char *data;

hdfql_variable_transient_register(&size);

hdfql_execute("SHOW SIZE foo.h5 \"Version\" INTO MEMORY 0");

printf("String size: %lld\n", size);

data = malloc(size);

hdfql_variable_transient_register(&data);

hdfql_execute("SELECT FROM foo.h5 \"Version\" INTO MEMORY 0");

printf("String data: %s\n", data);
```

Starting from HDFql version 2.5.0, the solution for this use-case is even simpler (as HDFql can automatically allocate the right amount of memory based on the size of the data stored in the attribute by specifying option `ALLOCATE`):

```
char *data;

hdfql_variable_transient_register(&data);

hdfql_execute("SELECT FROM foo.h5 \"Version\" INTO ALLOCATE MEMORY 0");

printf("String data: %s\n", data);
```

Comment: It does indeed seem to have a better designed API. Unfortunately I need to use the standard API . . .